# How to follow up with a recruiter that offered a referral?

Tags: hiring-process, referral

One week ago, myself and 49 other undergraduate students from around the country competed in a competition at the offices of one of the largest companies in the United States. This competition was related to programming and technology and, from what I've heard from previous attendees, was in sorts an interview and that attendees who performed well during this competition received offers shortly after. I've heard 7 days, or 1 week, after the end of the competition, and I'm slowly approaching that 7 days.

Near the end of the competition, a mentor from the company told our team (of 4) that they'd just completed evaluations for us, and that they'd be happy to refer us if we'd be interested in returning. Given this persons' contact email, what's the best way of asking for that referral?

Would it be okay to be upfront and just ask for it?

Comment: Yes, if someone says they're willing to do something, it's generally assumed to be appropriate to ask them to do it, and it shouldn't be particularly important that you pick the perfect set of words in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be fine to ask for it. You might send an email something like this:

> Dear <*recruiter name*>,
>
> Thanks for contacting me (or us) after the recent <*event name*>. It was a pleasure to meet you. You mentioned that you had completed evaluations for our team and that you'd be willing to refer us for <*whatever they offered to refer you for - jobs, internships, etc.*>. I (or we) are very interested in pursuing this opportunity. Please let me(us) know what you need from me(us) to proceed. I(we) look forward to hearing more about this opportunity.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> user3890432